# Как подключить классы-исключения из другой папки. Symfony

Tags: php, исключения, symfony

Создал отдельную папку `Exception`, где создал файлы в которых находятся классы-исключения наследуемые от класса `Exception`. Столкнулся с ошибкой `(1/2) RuntimeException
The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\CreateUserController" to be defined in file "/var/www/vendor/composer/../../src/Controller/CreateUserController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`

На западных источниках один из вариантов ошибки - неправильно указаный пути внутри файла.

Сам файл с ошибкой:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
namespace App\Portmone\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;

class CreateUserController
{

function createAction()
{
try {
  throw new InvalidException("Error Processing Request", 1);
}

catch (InvalidLoginException $e) {

}

catch (InvalidPassException $e){

}

catch (UserAlreadyExistException $e){

}

catch (DataBaseConnectionException $e){

}

catch (Exception $e){

 }
}
}
```

И один из файлов с классом-исключением:

```
<?php
namespace App\Portmone\Exception;

class UserAlreadyExistException extends \Exception { };
?>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Уберите второй namespace

Comment: @DmitryKozlov 
O_O. Помогло...Спасибо! а в чём сбсно было дело?

Comment: устанавливается тот namespace, что был последним. Но ваш контроллер в нем не найден

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, понял. Добавьте как ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо убрать лишний namespace

```
namespace App\Portmone\Exception;
```

возможно вы имели в виду

```
use App\Portmone\Exception;
```